# Create jDialog Swing with a message of error with image

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I'm new of Java and I want to do a jDialog that is opening when I push a button in the main JFrame and show a message of error in this way:

[image]

I can't put the image in another way in NetBeans? I create in the source package a directory with the image and a try much thing:

```
jDialog1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
jDialog1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/error_button.png")))));
jDialog1.pack();
jDialog1.setLocationByPlatform(true);

jDialog1.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: *"Is there a simple way to do this?"*  ..What's the hard way?  The dialog?  **Use a `JOptionPane`, it has inbult icons.**  Loading the image?  That is a one liner, as per the  code snippet.

Comment: BTW `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/error_button.png")))` can be shortened to `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/error_button.png"))` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use an [option pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) for this.  It includes its own icons according to the type of message (and look and feel).

[image]

```
Exception e = new Exception("Error!");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, e, e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: How to do for write another message and not "java.lang.Exception:Error!"?

Comment: `<head-desk>`  Did you actually bother to try reading the JavaDocs for the method I suggested?  It should be **pretty obvious** from a single glance.